# Do a Range Search for a Alphabetic Field

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I have a application that I save this in the database:

```
FromLetter ToLetter
AAA         AAZ
ABC         MNL
```

what I need is to search like this AAC and returns record 1 and FBC and return record 2. 
Is the same functionality if instead of letter I save dates. I need to do the same query.

I am using SQL Server and Entity Framework, any Idea how to do this?

Comment: You want a SQL Server answer or an EF answer?

Comment: SELECT * FROM a_table WHERE substr(`FromLetter`,1,1) =substr("AAC",1,1) OR substr(`FromLetter`,2,1) = substr("FBC", 2,1) LIMIT 2;  Look up the definition of `substr`, substring function for SQL server. This one is just an example `substr(input, start, length)`.  For dates, there is problably day(`fromLetter`) instead of `substr`.

Comment: @Frayer: substr is not SQL Server, neither is limit.

Comment: ... where stringtosearch between FromLetter and ToLetter ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be pretty straight forward.  Here is a Linq to Entities solution, ignoring case:

Entity Framework/Linq solution strings:

```
string yourValue = somevalue;
var result = (from r in db.ExampleTable
              where String.Compare(yourValue, r.FromLetter, true) == 1
              && String.Compare(yourValue, r.ToLetter, true) == -1
              select r).First();
```

Dates:

```
DateTime yourValue = somevalue;
var result = (from r in db.ExampleTable
              where yourValue >= r.FromDate
              && yourValue <= r.ToDate
              select r).First();
```

Comment: You cannot use >= and <= with string in Entity Framewrok, that is the error I get.

Comment: Sorry about that, I overlooked that .NET doesn't natively compare strings.  That should work fine for the dates, and I edited to show the correct way for strings as well, using String.Compare.  Just tested using VS 2010 and .NET 4

Answer (score 1):

I think it would be much easier to represent the `FromLetter` and `ToLetter` attributes using an integer. Especially if the length of the string is always just 3 - you can simply encode the number as:

```
(((letter1 - 'A') * 26 + (letter2 - 'A')) * 26) + (letter3 - 'A')
```

This will give you a number between 0 and 26^3 that represents the tripple and can be easily converted back to the string (using modulo and division as when converting numbers between numeric bases). This number fits into `Int32` comfortably (up to 6 letters).

Searching for a string within a specified range would then be a simple search for an integer within a numeric range (which is easy to do and efficient).

Answer (score 0):

Genius solution given by.... bunglestink

I wasted plenty of time in researching implementation of "between" clause for string in EF. This is helpful.